# Can I modify or extend ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to do some modifications in ChartJS, but I saw it is under license. Is it okay if I modify ChartJS? Or I have to create a new class which extends ChartJS? And how to extends ChartJS?

Answer (score 1):

ChartJS uses the MIT license. You can copy and modify it as long as you include a copy of the license with the altered library.

[See on github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js)

[The MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)